# The parameter can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I know there many answers to this question but I feel like I'm missing something that the other answers can't answer. I'm teaching myself Dart through their website. One of the examples they have is the following

```
String say(String from, String msg, [String? device]) {
  var result = '$from says $msg';
  if (device != null) {
    result = '$result with a $device';
  }
  return result;
}
Here’s an example of calling this function without the optional parameter:

assert(say('Bob', 'Howdy') == 'Bob says Howdy');
And here’s an example of calling this function with the third parameter:

assert(say('Bob', 'Howdy', 'smoke signal') ==
    'Bob says Howdy with a smoke signal');
```

I'm trying out something similar in Dartpad

```
void main() {
 print(testFunction('James', 'end', 'of it all'));
}

String testFunction(String start, String end, [String insert]){
  var result = '$start and this is the $end';
  if(insert != null) {
     result = '$result testing stuff $insert';
  }
  return result;
}
```

This ends up in the following error
`The parameter 'insert' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.`

I'm struggling to understand why that error is popping up considering I've added the third parameter in testFunction. Making the insert parameter optional solves the problem but why is it working for the Dart example and not my test?

Comment: change [String insert] to [String? insert]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `[String? insert]` in the function arguments. The Dart example has this as well in `[String? device]`.

Conceptually, the square brackets indicate that the parameter is optional, but "?" is still needed to indicate that the variable can be a null value

Comment: Ok, that kinda makes sense. Bit confusing though. Basically you have to set the optional parameter as null even when your passing the optional parameter

Comment: Yeah, think of it... because setting the argument as optional doesn't really affect the  type that is declared, and vice versa. `String insert` still means that the value is not nullable, regardless if it is optional `[String insert]`